# Spinner/Drop down загрузка данных (Sqlte)

Tags: sqlite, android-spinner, dropdown

всем привет,

у меня такой вопрос. Создала маленькую программу в при помощи которой можно добавлять x.Задания и сохранять в База данных. 
В программе 4. компонентов: EditTeхт(ADD_Task), Spinner/Drop down i EditText_description.
Сохранения данных работает. У проблема в том, что я  добавляю в EditText  Задания 1. прежде чем я его сохраню (при помощи add_button ) я пишу в нижнем EditText_description описание к Задании 1.(у каждой задании имеется описание). Ниже пишу описание к нему(despription не должен показаться в drop down). 
При нажатие в Буттон Адд сохраняет Задания 1. и Описание к нему в База данных. У меня не получается правильно написать функцию где данные загружаются из Sqlite в drop down. В данный момент в drop down загружаються и задния и описание.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто бы мне смог помочь разобраться с проблемой? Нужно исправить наверное код
еще вопрос. В EditText_output должны показаться описание. Только тогда, когда я выбираю задание 2. К задание 2. должно в EditText_output показаться описания к нему. Например. Выбираю в drop down задание 3. Выбрала задания, как только выбрала в EditText_output должен показаться описания к нему(описание 3.)

spasibo

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DataBaseHandler.java

```
    public void insertLabel(String label) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, label);
    values.put(KEY_DESCR, label);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

public void deleteLabel(String l) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(DATABASE_NAME, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { l });
}

/**
 * Getting all labels returns list of labels
 */
public List<String> getLabels() {
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    // String selectQuery = "SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            /*
             * do { labels.add(cursor.getString(1)); } while
             * (cursor.moveToNext());
             */
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(i));
            }

            // closing connection
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }

    }
    return labels;
```

Main.java

```
    loadSpinnerData();

    /**
     * Add new label button click listener
     */
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String label = inputLabel.getText().toString();
            String label1 = inputDescription.getText().toString();

            if (label.trim().length() > 0) {
                // database handler
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                // inserting new label into database
                db.insertLabel(label);
                db.insertLabel(label1);

                // making input filed text to blank
                inputLabel.setText("");
                inputDescription.setText("");

                // Hiding the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputLabel.getWindowToken(), 0);

                // loading spinner with newly added data
                loadSpinnerData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter label name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Function to load the spinner data from SQLite database
 */
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getLabels();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // String myState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    // String myStatesCapital = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    //
    // inputLabel.setText(myState);
    // inputDescription.setText(myState
    // + myStatesCapital);

    // inputDescription.setText(label );

}
```